# Push data from drop-down list to database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with adding data to MySQL with Laravel.
Let's say that we have a table "Books" with "categories" column, let's also say that there are only 3 categories which can be choose by User. So we have a drop-down list with "Thrillers, Horrors, Actions" and when we want to add a New Book, we have to provide its title and also select from drop-down list a category.
I wrote:

```
create.blade.php
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('title') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label>Book title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="The title of the book" value="{{ old('title') ? : $books->title }}">
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('category_id') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <label>Category</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="category_id">
                        <option value="{{ old('name') ? : $books->category_id }}">Horror</option>
                        <option value="{{ old('name') ? : $books->category_id }}">Action</option>
                        <option value="{{ old('name') ? : $books->category_id }}">Thriller</option>

                </select>
            </div>
```

But i get an error :/

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'category_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `books` (`category_id`, `title`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , 2018-08-07 19:37:28, 2018-08-07 19:37:28))
```

Also I'm a newbie in PHP and Laravel so please contain a short description for every solution. Thank you!

```
BooksRequest.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class BooksRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
        ];
    }
}

BooksController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Books;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Services\TranslationService;
use App\Translation;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\BooksRequest;

class BooksController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $books = books::all();
        return view('books.index', compact('books'));
    }
    public function create()
    {
        $books = new Books();
        return view('books.create', compact('books'));
    }
    public function store(BooksRequest $request)
    {
        $books = new Books();
        $books ->title = $request->title;
        $books ->category_id= $request->category_id;

        if($books ->save()) {
            return redirect()->route('books.index')->with(['success' => true, 'message_type' => 'success', 'message' => 'Success '.$request->title.'.']);
        }
        return back()->with(['success' => false, 'message_type' => 'danger', 'message' => 'Bad'.$request->title.'. Try later.']);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure you added `category_id` in fillable in  Book model?

Comment: Probably need to include the code for saving this `book`; might be missing `$book->category_id = $request->input("category_id");`, or `category_id` in `Book::create([...])`; too much to guess at here.

Comment: I added controller and request in topic post, please look

Comment: First note; watch your naming conventions; Table should be plural (`books`), but Model should be singular `Book`. Also, variable name `$books` suggests multiple, but it's actually only a single record. Beyond that, it looks ok. If you do a `dd($request->input());` in your `store()` function, what do you get?

Comment: ``array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "2zg0tdrkOgIrWgDEWBNRKd8p9BSEEsFaTabrNBKo"
  "id" => null
  "title" => "Working :)"
  "categorry_id" => null
]``

Comment: It seems like "value" for categorry is not passed to controller. If user press "horror" it should write in database column under category_id field the name "horror_book".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Input(„valuename”) with request and it’s working :) 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests